# Can I hide my application in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an Android App only for my clients and I want to publish on Google Play. Is there a way to hide the application from searches and make it only accessible by URL? To use the app, people need a license, and I don't want someone searching for "XYZ" to see my app.

Hosting the APK on my servers is not a solution, since I update it very often and prefer the Play Store update system.

Comment: Why would you like to publish an app that is not searchable for any device? Just don't publish it and upload it to your server.

Comment: It's a stupid semi-solution, but how about setting huge price, and then adding clients as test accounts?

Comment: Thanks all for reply. @Chinask: I want to publish because the update system is very comfortable for clients and me.

Comment: @chester1000: Someone will buy it thinking he is buying the license.

Comment: I mean huge price, like $999. If your program's licence could be worth more thou, think about implementing some kind of authorization mechanism AFTER app is installed, so user will get prompted to authorize, and only after that additional (crucial) data will be downloaded, because there's absolutely no way to make published app "private".

Comment: @Carlos3dx can you find any solution regarding this issue? let me know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Play now allows you a new way to distribute internal applications(*Google Play Private Channel*):

> The Google Play Private Channel for Google Apps (the Private Channel) allows Google Apps domains to distribute internal Android applications to their users through the Google Play Store.

[Here](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html) you can find the announce on Google Enterprise Blog and [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992) the instructions to set up this feature.

Comment: Right, but you can only publish to Google Apps users which are part of the same domain - hence not for customers... See quote from google docu: 'When you distribute apps using a Private Channel, only other users of your Google Apps domain can access these apps'

Answer (score 1):

One way is to publish it very temporarily, then tell everyone to download it, and right after that to unpublish the app.

Another way is to put the right description of the app (alpha, preview,...) and allow only selected users to actually use it (others can download, but it won't work for them). you can let only the selected users to make it work using any method you wish.

However it's done, you should think how to make the license expire at some point.

Another way is to put it on a server and make the app check for a new update every now and then. You might also use google drive, but I'm not sure how.