# How to make my android Application unsearchable on the Play Store?

Tags: android

I want to hide my app from play store. I would like that only those users who has link of my android application can install and use my application.

Is there any way?

Comment: remove the application, and do a alpha release, select the users email you want to share. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Yes you can do this. There is a link available which is already answered. Please find link if this help you really good.
[Hide app from google play store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718505/can-i-hide-my-application-in-google-play-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go for [Google Play Private Channel for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)  allows Google Apps domains to distribute internal Android applications to their users through the Google Play Store.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want it searched, why do you want it in the Play Store?

Just remove it from the Play Store and email your APK to your users.

Comment: Auto-updates are a great thing