# Google play possible to prevent app from showing up when searching

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

I have an app I wrote for a small business that is being used by <10 people. Ideally i'd like to use Google Play to distibute updates, collect crash logs, and review device configurations.

Is it possible to prevent the app from showing up when people search for it, so I could just distribute the link that the owner can share with his employees?

I am trying to avoid setting up EMM and paying for enterprise level distribution.

And I am aware of the security concerns of people accidently stumbling on the app in the play store when it's listed under new. Preventing people from accessing it via search is all I'm concerned about at this point.

Comment: Side note: if this is not possible, is there a safe alternative app store that I can distribute updates on? (Like FDroid but I don't want to publish source code)

Comment: Google play allows you to release alpha and beta prototypes that are only distributed via links, or invited people via email.

Comment: This seems to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718505/can-i-hide-my-application-in-google-play-store

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24177028/295004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Alpha or Beta channel to do this. If the app is published Alpha or Beta only it is not visible in the general Play store to anyone outside the Alpha.

However, this is not a long term or multi-customer solution. Setting up an EMM based solution is much better, and need not be that expensive.

Comment: Are there any time limits to how long an app can be in alpha or beta testing?

Comment: No time limits at the moment.